# What is the name of the buffer that can be overflowed buf, msg, len or out

Tags: c, stack, overflow, variable-assignment

I am new to this and I can't seem to understand can you please help me identify the buffer that can be overflowed and why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define S 100
#define N 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char out[S];
    char buf[N];
    char msg[] = "Welcome to the argument echoing program\n";
    int len = 0;
    buf[0] = '\0';
    printf(msg);

    while (argc) {
        sprintf(out, "argument %d is %s\n", argc-1, argv[argc-1]);
        argc--;``
        strncat(buf,out,sizeof(buf)-len-1);
        len = strlen(buf);
    }
    printf("%s",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, if you post code here, indent it properly. This is horrible to read. Then, we are not here to do your homework. To solve it, check all functions that write into one of the buffers, and think of situations where it might overflow.

Comment: `len = strlen(buf);` seems to pay quadratic costs for a linear problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you very much I was thinking in that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
sprintf(out, "argument %d is %s\n", argc - 1, argv[argc - 1]);
```

When you face a problem like this one, it's always a good idea to go through your code commenting lines until the program stops crashing. Then you will know where the bug is :D